# Vector3.Distance for comparing mouse and GameObject distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-engine

I have some mouseinput , which I converted into a Vector3.
Now I used this Input and calculated the distance between the mouseinput and my gameobjects position.
The method returned a float as my distance , which i compared to my MaxDistance float.
So when my Inputdistance is less or equal to my MaxDistance , it should destroy my GameObject.
But when I run my game, nothing works.
I also tried to increase the MaxDistance value , but it didn't helped either.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tropfen : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 10.0f;
Rigidbody2D rb;
AudioSource source;
[SerializeField] AudioClip[] soundClips;
[SerializeField] GameObject particleEffect;
[SerializeField] float maxDistance = 20f;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime);
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    source.clip = soundClips[Random.Range(0, soundClips.Length)];
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector3 screenPos = Input.mousePosition;
    Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos);

    float TropfenTouchDistance = Vector3.Distance(screenPos, gameObject.transform.position);

    if ( TropfenTouchDistance <= maxDistance)
    {
        TropfenDestruction();
    }
}

private void TropfenDestruction()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(source.clip, transform.position);
    GameObject effect = Instantiate(particleEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as 
    GameObject;
    Destroy(effect, 2f);
    FindObjectOfType<Gameplay>().IncreaseScore(1);
}
}
```

Comment: You're not using the return value from Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint - could that be the problem when doing the distance calculation ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `screenPos` is still in screen pixel space since you didn't use the output of [`ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

```
var screenPos = Input.mousePosition;
var worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos);

// It's redundant going through the gameObject here btw
var TropfenTouchDistance = Vector3.Distance(worldPos, transform.position);

if ( TropfenTouchDistance <= maxDistance)
{
    TropfenDestruction();
}
```

Anyway note that [`ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) needs also a `Z` component

> A screen space position (often mouse x, y), **plus a z position for depth** (for example, a camera clipping plane).

indicating how far from the given `Camera` the point should be projected into the world.

---

In order to overcome this you can use  a mathematical [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) so you can get exactly a point projected next to the object using [`ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) in a [`Plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html)

```
// In general store the camera reference as Camera.main is very expensive!
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;


private void Update()
{
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;

    var plane = new Plane(_camera.transform.forward, transform.position);
    var ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if(plane.Raycast(ray, out var hitDistance))
    {  
        var worldPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitDistance);
        var TropfenTouchDistance = Vector3.Distance(worldPos, transform.position);

        if ( TropfenTouchDistance <= maxDistance)
        {
            TropfenDestruction();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I used your suggested code but my Gameobjects are destroyed immediately, when they get instantiated.

Comment: well because as you have it your `Update` method is always executed and not waiting for any user input ... possible that your `maxDistance` of `20` units is to big and therefore all conditions are always fulfilled to destroy an object?