# How to follow mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I have a question we can follow mouse position 2d game like this in new Input System

```
void Update()
        {
                transform.position = position;
        }


 public void OnMouseMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
        {
         if(playerHealth.health>0)
            {
                position= Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(context.ReadValue<Vector2>());
            }

        }
```

Its Work fine Ortoghraphic Camera, but
When i convert the Perspective Camera doesnt work
I need that perspective Camera... So how can i do that

Comment: `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` expects a `Vector3` where the `z` component defines the **distance from camera** so how far in front of the camera this point should be in your world. If you use a `Vector2` as parameter it is implicitly converted into a `Vector3` with `z = 0` -> the position is on the same depth as the camera. For an orthographic camera this doesn't really matter but for a perspective camera this results in wrong positions according to the perspective angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an edited version of [this previous answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174045/1092820).

As mentioned in the comment above, note that [`ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) needs also a `Z` component

> A screen space position (often mouse x, y), **plus a z position for depth** (for example, a camera clipping plane).

indicating how far from the given `Camera` the point should be projected into the world.

In order to overcome this you can use  a mathematical [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) so you can get a point projected next to the object using [`ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) in a [`Plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html) (which is a mathematical raycast, has nothing to do with physics or collision detection)

```
// In general store the camera reference as Camera.main is very expensive!
[SerializeField] Camera camera;

void Start()
{
    camera = Camera.main;
    // ...
}

public void OnMouseMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if(playerHealth.health > 0)
    {
        var plane = new Plane(camera.transform.forward, transform.position);
        var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(context.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        plane.Raycast(ray, out var hitDistance);
        position = ray.GetPoint(hitDistance);
    }
}
```

Comment: This Realy Works Fine! Thank you So much!